# Quality problem with questions here

Tags: discussion

I first used SF and then discovered UL. The problem with UL is that most questions would need the answer RTFM and should be downvoted. I admire the people investing their time answering these questions.

On the other hand the more complex, good/deep questions regarding UL can still be found at SF (if you are able to find them).

Would it be a good idea to ask the SF mods to change the FAQ there to encourage people to go to UL instead? Should we comment more questions in SF and ask to move these questions here?

Comment: sometimes the problem is finding the manual you should be reading... or finding what subsection it's named under.

Comment: @xenoterracide nothing against that sort of questions. There are some horrible complex man-pages or man pages with missing information out there. But asking "how do I set up SSL on httpd" does not show much research effort.

Comment: See also [Should we close general reference questions?](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/692) . I don't think we have a big problem with general reference questions here, but feel free to downvote them.

Comment: @Nils the number of acronyms in this question makes my eyes hurt...

Comment: **UL** Unix and Linux;
**SF** Server Fault;
**RFTM** read the FINE manual;
**FAQ** frequently asked questions

Comment: Imho, if you think most questions are affected, you should do a list of questions from one day, and indicate, which of them should be moved, to show, that it is indeed a majority.

Comment: @userunknown the movement regards movement from SF to UL. But quality seems to rise in UL as more and more users get over here (from SF).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We generally don't try to steal scope from other sites; that is, if a question is on-topic for another site, we don't try to get them to redirect users here now that this site exists as well, since we wouldn't want to suddenly lose all questions on a given topic if a more specific Stack Exchange site opened up

RTFM is a fine line. For example, the `sed` man page contains enough information to tell you how to write all possible `sed` scripts -- any question on writing a `sed` script could be solved if the user read the man page and worked their way through it, but often the thing they're trying to do is complicated enough that I think it's fine to ask here

On the other hand, questions like "how do I make `du` use human-readable output?" can probably be closed -- the man page literally says "-h, --human-readable -- print sizes in human readable format", you just need to search it. I've seen those before, but I don't think we have many questions like that

Comment: unless of course you're using an old version of `du` which didn't have that options ;)

Comment: @xenoterracide the "-h" option is not that old... ;-)

Comment: So what about the FAQ idea? I think there are too many people on SF that simply do not know about UL. And it would be good for SF, too if some questions were diverted to more specialized forums.

Comment: @Nils That's what the first paragraph was about. If they want to add us they can, you'll need to talk to the SF mods, but they probably don't want to say "Hey, Unix/Linux questions are fine here, but you should go to this other site instead"